# custom runtime environment - libpthread segmentation fault

Tags: c, c++, dynamic-linking, shared-library

I have built a project using gcc 4.9.2 (libstdc++.so.6.0.20). When I want to run that program on the virtual machine which is equipped with gcc 4.6.3 (libstdc++.so.6.0.16) I have to deliver libstd++/libc in the same versions as on the build machine. I follow these steps:

- export LD_LIBRARY_PATH (custom glibc build with proper kernel version and libstdc++)
- run command: LD_DEBUG=libs LD_PRELOAD=/path_to_custom_glibc/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 myApp

I get an output which informs that a program crash during **calling init: /path_to_custom_glibc/libpthread.so.0**

What might be wrong ?

**Edit1**
Core dump doesn't show where a segmentation fault occurs but LD_DEBUG=all returns a more precise info than LD_DEBUG=libs:

> symbol=__libc_dl_error_tsd;
>   lookup in file=/path_to_custom_glibc/libc.so.6 [0]
>         3539: binding file /path_to_custom_glibc/libpthread.so.0 [0] to /path_to_custom_glibc/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__libc_dl_error_tsd' [GLIBC_PRIVATE]
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `gdb` and then a `bt` might be handy to know...

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY` is unknown by the dynamic linker. Do you have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in mind?

Comment: Yes, I mean LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I will try to analyze core dump.

Comment: Please see Edit1